# Apache Mahout build failure mahout-hdfs

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, build, mahout

I have a ubuntu 12.04 machine with oracle java SE, jdk 1.7 and maven 3.3.3. I cloned apache mahout from https://github.com/apache/mahout.git on 07.09.2015.
When I tried to build mahout using "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" I got the following error and the build failed.

"Failed to execute goal on project mahout-hdfs: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.mahout:mahout-hdfs:jar:0.11.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.mahout:mahout-math:jar:tests:0.11.1-SNAPSHOT in http://repository.apache.org/snapshots"

Could someone identify what went wrong? I didn't install hadoop but I set "export MAHOUT_LOCAL=true". So I hope not having hadoop is not the issue. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: That artifact is [present](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/mahout/mahout-math/0.11.1-SNAPSHOT/) in the repository. Try cleaning your m2 repo and building with `mvn -U clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

Comment: I'm new to maven, so could you please explain how to locate m2 repo and clean it.

Comment: m2 repo is typically located in `~/.m2/repository`. It's a simple folder structure that you can delete safely (Maven will re-download everything).

Comment: Actually this is the failure I got first "Failed to execute goal on project mahout-hdfs: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.mahout:mahout-hdfs:jar:0.11.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.mahout:mahout-math:jar:tests:0.11.1-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots) "

The error message I previously gave in my question is the one I got when I gave the command mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true again without resolving the issue. So does your solution still applicable?

Comment: I can't test it right now so it's a shot in the dark but it can resolve your problem.

Comment: I cleaned the repo with "rm -rvf ~/.m2/repository " command. Now to build what's the reason for using "mvn -U clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" with "-U" ? Is it necessary to use "-U"?

Comment: -U forces Maven to re-download dependencies, whatever the update policy.

Comment: Your Solution was a success !!!